# created grouped frequency on the base of data and class intervals

Tags: python, numpy

I have small problem related to grouped frequency distribution task, i have  read  a data from csv file  and  calculated all necessary parameters(min, max, range, clas_with, low_class, upper_class)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
selected_data =np.array(pd.read_csv("data.csv"))
#  გამოვიანგარიშოთ ყველა საჭირო პარამეტრი
#მინიმალური და მაქსიმალური ელემენტი
min_element =np.min(selected_data)
max_element =np.max(selected_data)
# განვსაზღვროთ კლასების რაოდენობა
num_class =7  # ნებისმიერი რიცხვი  5  სა  და 20 ს შორის
# განვსაზღვროთ გაბნევის დიაპაზონი
range_interval =max_element - min_element
if range_interval % num_class ==0: # თუ არაა ნაშითი, გავზარდით კლასების რაოდენობა ერთით
     num_class =num_class+1
# განვსაზღვროთ კლასის სიგანე
width =math.ceil(range_interval /num_class)
# შევქმნათ  ქვედა  და ზედა კლასები
low_class =np.arange(min_element,max_element,width)
upper_clas = low_class + width -1
```

dont pay attention to the comments, it is in georgian language, my task is to calculated frequncies based on selected data,  idea is  following: for pair of low_class and upper_class bounds, i want to know  how many element from original  matrix is fit, values of low class and upper class are :

Low_class values :

```
[100 105 110 115 120 125 130]
```

Upper_class Values

```
[104 109 114 119 124 129 134]
```

what i want is to calculate how many number fit between

100-104
105-109
.
.
.
of course those pair i can create using zip command, for instance
print(list(zip(low_class,upper_class)))

will return

```
[(100, 104), (105, 109), (110, 114), (115, 119), (120, 124), (125, 129), (130, 134)]
```

but how to calculate frequency?i have tried following code

```
# class  pairs
class_pairs =list(zip(low_class,upper_clas))
list_result =[]
for (low_bound, upper_bound) in class_pairs:
    result =np.sum([selected_data>=low_bound and selected_data<=upper_bound])
    list_result.append(result)
```

but it gives me following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dato/PycharmProjects/my_first_python/read_data.py", line 25, in <module>
    result =np.sum([selected_data>=low_bound and selected_data<=upper_bound])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

- To chain multiple conditions on numpy array you need to use `&` operator.
- Below code should work.

```py
# class  pairs
class_pairs =list(zip(low_class,upper_clas))
list_result =[]
for (low_bound, upper_bound) in class_pairs:
    result =np.sum(selected_data[(selected_data>=low_bound) & (selected_data<=upper_bound)])
    list_result.append(result)
```

- Example

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
np.sum(a[(a>=3) & (a<=6)])
```

output:

> 18

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.sum` in a loop like this is inefficient.
What you want is roughly what [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) provides.

Here is how to use it:

```py
# Note that list_result is a numpy array
list_result = numpy.histogram(selected_data, low_class + [max_element])[0]
```

Example:

```py
selected_data = [100, 101, 105, 111, 112, 113, 133]
low_class = [100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130]
max_element = 133
list_result = numpy.histogram(selected_data, low_class + [max_element])[0]
print(list_result)
```

Output:

```
[2 1 3 0 0 0 1]
```